# Use the dataframe output of for loop outside of the loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically I'm trying to create two dataframes to be compared (to see which values that exist in one dataframe are missing in the other).

One dataframe is created using a for loop and going through Google Cloud buckets and listing the files and using those filenames as the column in the first dataframe:

```
for folderName in bucketFolder:
    blob_path = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketName, prefix=folderName)
    for blob in blob_path:
        blob_list = pd.DataFrame((str(blob.name).rsplit("/", 1)[-1]).split())
```

The other dataframe is created from reading the list of filenames from an excel spreadsheet:

```
spreadsheet_filenames = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(spreadsheetFile,
                usecols=['Filename']))code here
```

I want to use the dataframe blob_list outside of that for loop so I can compare it to the spreadsheet_filenames dataframe using this code:

```
blob_spreadsheet_matches = blob_list[0].apply(lambda s1: spreadsheet_filenames['Filename'].apply(lambda s2: s1 in s2).any())enter code here
```

Just not sure how to use the blob_list dataframe outside of the for loop.

Comment: `blob_list = [pd.DataFrame((str(blob.name).rsplit("/", 1)[-1]).split()) for blob in blob_path]`

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, unfortunately I just realized I screwed up when I posted the code as it's actually a nested loop, I edited the code sample

Comment: `blob_list = pd.DataFrame(...)` This creates one dataframe.  It is not a list...

Comment: You can just use @JohnGordon answer as is, or replace the inner loop with the line of code in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the name `blob_list`, it seems like you expect that variable to actually be a list, which it is not.

Try this:

```
blob_list = []
for folderName in bucketFolder:
    blob_path = storage_client.list_blobs(bucketName, prefix=folderName)
    for blob in blob_path:
        frame = pd.DataFrame((str(blob.name).rsplit("/", 1)[-1]).split())
        blob_list.append(frame)
```